# How to do onClicked programatic injection with content scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I created a Google Chrome Action extension. It needn't use a popup page.
It has a background persistent process/page which constantly analyzes page source data. However, this is a separate process and I don't want to do the UI programmatic injection from background, as in official examples.

I designed the script that dynamically generates the UI (results) on top of the user's page, that needs to appear when the Action icon is clicked. I need to do this programmatic injection by using content script, not background nor popup pages.

But it won't work, since the content script is a 'lonely island' that doesn't communicate with other extensions and doesn't have full access permission to the chrome. Thus, when using the following code in the content script :

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"}); }
```

This is part of my manifest file :

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "Show my visitors"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*.google.com/*",
    "background"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

It doesn't work because the content script pressumably doesn't have access to the browserAction.onClicked method. I really need to do programmatic injection when the action extension icon is clicked, by using content scripts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` cannot reside in a content script.

It must be listened to in the background script. That is the main purpose of a background script: the unified place to react to events. It's so prevalent that Chrome even introduced a special class of background pages, [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), for background pages that only react to events.

You need to decide whether you go manifest injection route or programmatic injection route.

If you inject your code via manifest, your script will always be loaded and you can use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to trigger code in it.

If you decide to inject code on click only, you should call `chrome.tabs.executeScript` from the listener, as you did in your code. Again, if you need to communicate between the two components, use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Have another look at the [Architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) while you're at it.

Comment: Thanks @Xan. I will use the messaging interface to send a notice from the background listener to the content script, whenever the icon is clicked, to activate the injected script.

Comment: Do consider the implications: if the content script is always injected but rarely activated, it means you're always using some resources like memory per tab that matches. It may be worth to switch to PI if the content script does nothing else.

Comment: Of course, programatic injection is the way I need it as I also specified in my post. The manifest file with auto-injection of the content script was just for reference. Thanks